# Define custom list-style-type in CSS

Tags: css

I want to ask, if is that possible (something like font-face). Example:

```
@list-style-type {
  list-style-image: 'myCustomStyle';
  src: url('url-to-image');
}

ul {
  list-style-type: myCustomStyle;
}
```

Is there something like that? I know I can do that with classes on element and then set custom image, but that is not my point. I have issue from my company and something like this would be very nice.

Comment: Ultra short answer: No.

Comment: If you are using a pre-processor you could do this with a mixin, for example. Otherwise you will have to use classes.

Comment: @somethinghere Yeah, compile-to-CSS languages are the way to go if you really want it.

Comment: Ok, it was just question. Now I have to find another way to do it.

Comment: @Kroltan I knew that one. I mistyped it. Dang, now I look like an idiot :) I did change it but I'll admit fault in this comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS as currently defined and implemented, you cannot. The values of the [`list-style-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#list-style) property are a set of keywords, somewhat different in different specifications and implementations, but even the syntax does not allow for any custom values to be added.

There is work in progress to define [CSS Lists and Counters Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/), which would extend the syntax and semantics, to allow custom values to be defined in `@counter-style` rules, using constructs designed as part of [CSS Counter Styles Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-counter-styles-3/). This is planned to include the possibility of defining a named value that uses a custom image, or a construct that contains a custom image as part of it. So far, it seems that there are no implementations of this in released versions of browsers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34141979/470749 shows how to use `ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '✓';
}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use li background image,

```
<li style="background:url()">list text here </li>
```

Or you can use like

```
ul {
list-style-image: url('imageName.png');
```

}

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: I know that, but I wanted to define **custom** list type. I said that I don't want it by this way.